# Is there a possibly way to lock/Installed only my application in my device?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm created and setting up my new android application and i don't know how to *attach/lock* my application on my device

Well by mean *attach/lock* for example, the app i want is Facebook application to be in my screen and device, if user using my device and logout from Facebook, it can't back into android home, and it just show login form, 
so my device only have Facebook app and cannot open another app or install anything, so user in my device can only access Facebook app.

is there a possibly way or documentation so i can archive this?

Comment: I am confused by your question. Are you asking how to have only your app on a device all the time? Or how to setup the app to automatically log out if the user logs out of Facebook? Or to take over the device upon install without the user doing anything beyond running the app?

Comment: first i am sorry cause i cant explain my question correctly, but like you said i am asking to have only my app on my device all the time, and yes i used facebook as an example of my explanation

Comment: For devices owned by business, look into "Android kiosk mode" or device management: [Android documentation on dedicated devices](https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/dedicated-devices). [Locked task mode](https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/dedicated-devices/lock-task-mode) is probably what you are after.

Comment: i will check the documentation thanks and good day sir

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is impossible unless your device has been rooted. Because of every apps on android devices are running in their sandboxes by default.

Comment: so that's impossible?, i don't want my device to be rooted. by you mean I have to make my own Android OS which specializes in installing my app?

Comment: Yes, I think so. Because of security and privacy, you cannot use your app to monitor another one unless your app has root permission.